# reason of segmented code on x64

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, intel

I am beginner in x64, and when I was going through the Intel TRM, I found that segmentation is removed in x64(only the CS register is used for attributes). But when I dis-assembled simple helloWorld.c on x64 (using gcc on .c and using objdump on .o file) then there were segments defined. 
My question is: why there are segment in dis-assembled code on x64 while segmentation is not supported??

Comment: CPU segments are different than ELF segments.

Comment: By the way, FS and GS are also still used, but they only supply offsets (no attributes or limit).

Comment: In the case of Windows, I had the impression that either FS or GS is used to access a "per thread" structure.

Comment: How's CPU segment differ from ELF segments?? And even with the difference, what's the purpose of keeping segments in assembly files of x64 while they are at flat memory model..?? @NayukiMinase  (Is it related to read-only pages in x64 for code or read only data or something else and enhanced..) Please elaborate..!!  :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma because they have different attributes (some are readonly, hopefully only the code segment is executable, some contain no data in the binary but represent zero-initialized space)

Comment: Harold is correct. Also, the file segments can place different parts of the file at different virtual addresses - not necessarily contiguously. (The reason I'm not writing an answer is because I don't have full knowledge to answer your question adequately.)